# Times font looks different when produced on different computers as the output of the same TexShop version.

Tags: fonts, pdf, texshop, output, times

The fact that the Times font in the PDFs copies of the same TexShop files looks considerably different depending on which computer I use has been a mistery for me for a long time. Can anyone please suggest what I should do to have my Times font looks always like in the first piece given below? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same versions of the TeX distributions and/or fonts?

Comment: You say that you use `TeX` + `DVI`. But how do you produce PDF files? If you use ghostscript to convert PS to PDF, it may embed different versions of Times font coming from different OS....

Comment: Yes, both versions are up to date (though, even 5 years ago I had the same issue, no matter what TeXShop versions I used on both comps) and both use Ghostscript. So essentially, yes, it looks like both machines want to embed different versions of the Times font. I just copied the Times font (Times.dfont) from the Font Library of the laptop and tried to copy it into the Font Library of the iMac. The iMac resolved the fonts as duplicates. Note that I can view both fonts in PDFs on both comps.

Comment: Use `pdffonts` or the properties in your PDF viewer to see which fonts each PDF is actually using.

Comment: You're on the right track cfr! The upper file has NimbusRomNo9L (Embedded subset), while the lower one has LASY10, Tex - xipa10 and Times-Roman (Embedded subset). Any ideas how I can install the Nimbus font on my other comp so that TeXShop uses it instead of the Times (while keeping the \{times} command intact, as it is in the upper file)?